# Phone Number Translator Error

Tags: java, string, phone-number

This program is supposed to take a a phone number with letters in it, and translate it to all numbers, but I keep receiving these three errors in compilation.

> Phone_ronhoward.java:30: error: 'else' without 'if'       else if(letter <
>   'G')      ^
>
> Phone_ronhoward.java:73: error: ')' expected      for(int i = 0; i <
>   phoneNumber.length; i++;)
>                                                   ^
>
> Phone_ronhoward.java:73: error: illegal start of expression       for(int
>   i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length; i++;)
>                                                    ^
>
> 3 errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phone_ronhoward
{
 public static char getNumber(char upperCaseLetter)
 {
    char returnValue = 0;

    if(letter < 'A')
    {
        returnValue = '0';
    }
    else if(letter < 'D');
    {
        returnValue = '2';
    }
    else if(letter < 'G')
    {
        returnValue = '3';
    }
    else if(letter < 'J')
    {
        returnValue = '4';
    }
    else if(letter < 'M')
    {
        returnValue = '5';
    }
    else if(letter < 'P')
    {
        returnValue = '6';
    }
    else if(letter < 'T')
    {
        returnValue = '7';
    }
    else if(letter < 'W')
    {
        returnValue = '8';
    }
    else if(letter <= 'Z')
    {
        returnValue = '9';
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = '0';
    }
    return returnValue;

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the phone number string: ");

    String phoneNumber = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    for(int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length; i++;)
    {

        getNumber();

    }
} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semi-colon after `else if(letter < 'D');`, just remove it:

```
    else if(letter < 'D')
```

Comment: Yeah wow I just noticed it. Now it compiles but when I run the program it just prints this. If I input 1800flowers, it prints           
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
5
6
9
3
7
7, instead of 1800FLOWERS

Comment: It's because numbers are before A, so they get inside the first if statement

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent your issue, which converts all numbers into zeroes:

```
public static char getNumber(char upperCaseLetter)
{
    char returnValue;

    if((letter >= 'A') && (letter < 'D'))
    {
        returnValue = '2';
    }
    else if(letter < 'G')
    {
        returnValue = '3';
    }
    else if(letter < 'J')
    {
        returnValue = '4';
    }
    else if(letter < 'M')
    {
        returnValue = '5';
    }
    else if(letter < 'P')
    {
        returnValue = '6';
    }
    else if(letter < 'T')
    {
        returnValue = '7';
    }
    else if(letter < 'W')
    {
        returnValue = '8';
    }
    else if(letter <= 'Z')
    {
        returnValue = '9';
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = upperCaseLetter;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phone_ronhoward {
    public static char getNumber(char letter) {
        char returnValue = 0;
        if (letter < 'A') {
            returnValue = '0';
        } else if (letter < 'D') {
            returnValue = '2';
        } else if (letter < 'G') {
            returnValue = '3';
        } else if (letter < 'J') {
            returnValue = '4';
        } else if (letter < 'M') {
            returnValue = '5';
        } else if (letter < 'P') {
            returnValue = '6';
        } else if (letter < 'T') {
            returnValue = '7';
        } else if (letter < 'W') {
            returnValue = '8';
        } else if (letter <= 'Z') {
            returnValue = '9';
        } else {
            returnValue = '0';
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the phone number string: ");
        String phoneNumber = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(getNumber(phoneNumber.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am just getting an "else without if" error on line 30.

Comment: Could you specify the code of the error line? In my code line 30 is `public static void main(String[] args) {`.

Comment: I fixed it. I had an extra semicolon. Now it compiles but when I run the program it just prints this. If I input 1800flowers, it prints 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 6 9 3 7 7, instead of 1800FLOWERS

Comment: Yes, so what is your expected output for the input "1800flowers"?

Comment: Also, @fmbesteiro is correct - need an additional "if" to exclude the numeric input cases.